# find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product (incorrect message)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

i keep getting incorrect message please explain me what is wrong?

here is the challenge question:
Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.
Example

For`inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3],`the output should be `adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21.`

7 and 3 produce the largest product.

here is my code answer:

```
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
for(let i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
    let prod =Math.max(inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]);
   

}
 return prod;
}
```

Comment: Hi aya, How did you do with your problem? Have you seen my answer? I think it might help you. please give some feedbacks. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

##### Things you should Correct:

1. When the index reaches to the length of `inputArray`, the
   `inputArray[i+1]` will throw an `OutOfIndex` error, since the
   indexes' range are from `0` to `inputArray.length - 1`, and here the
   last `i` will have the value of `inputArray.length - 1` then the
   value of `i+1` will be `inputArray.length` and it's not correct.
2. You should make a variable (consider `max_res`) to save the prevoius maximum result and compare it to new results.
3. Define the `prod` variable before the `for loop`, because variables which are first defined in the `loop` they won't be accessible after the `loop` ends.
4. Define a vairable to store the index of `i` that makes the maximum value, since the question wanted the index ,too.

You should change your code like this, to get the correct output:

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  let max_res = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  let res_index = -1;
  let prod = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++) {
    prod = Math.max(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1]);  
    if (prod > max_res){
        max_res = prod;
        let res_index = i;
    }
  }
  return prod;
}

let inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
let prod = adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray)

console.log(prod);
```

Comment: thanks for explation but when i edited it i kept getting incorrect message there is another mistake i cant get to it

Comment: I Updated my answer, it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You have to get the max of two numbers as

```
sum = Math.max(sum, inputArray[i] * (inputArray[i + 1] ?? 1));
```

**2)** You also have to handle the last case where `i + 1` will be `undefined` then you have multiply by `1`. You can use [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
(inputArray[i + 1] ?? 1)
```

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    sum = Math.max(sum, inputArray[i] * (inputArray[i + 1] ?? 1));
  }
  return sum;
}

const inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3];
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray));
```

Comment: At `i = 5` , `inputArr[i + 1]` will be `undefined` so `??` is [null coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator.

Comment: The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

Answer (score 0):

`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` will allow the smallest integer because this needs to find the largest sum which may include negative integers.

```js
function solution(inputArray) {
    let largestProduct = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if(inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1] > largestProduct) {
            largestProduct = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return largestProduct;
}
```